# Sanitize filepath string and only allow 1 trailing slash at the end

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, filepath, sanitization

I need to remove non alphanumeric characters except _ (underscore) and - dash and only one / (forward slash) from the end of a string.

```
$string = 'controller_123/method///';
```

or

```
$string = 'controller_123/method/';
```

Both should return: `'controller_123/method/'`;

What I have tried up to now:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]\/$/', '', $string);
```

Comment: Can't you just str_replace "//" to "/"?

Comment: It would be much more eficient to use $string = rtrim($string, '/');

Comment: rtrim removes all slashes from the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with arrays of patterns and replacements; the first to remove non-alphanumeric characters other than `_`, `-` and `/`, and the second to remove all but the last trailing `/`:

```
$string = 'controller_123/method///';
echo preg_replace(array('#[^\w/-]+#', '#/+$#'), array('', '/'), $string);
```

Output:

```
controller_123/method/
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/kHM5l)

The regex can be improved by noting that we want to remove all `/` before the one at the end of the line, and using a positive lookahead to match those. Then all matches can simply be replaced with an empty string:

```
$string = 'contr*@&oller_123////method///';
echo preg_replace('#[^\w/-]+|/(?=/+$)#', '', $string);
```

Output:

```
controller_123////method/
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/0YhQt)

Comment: Nice one but it also removes multiple slashes between words. Example : controller_123/////method/// will return controller_123/method/. I actually keep the last 1 forward slash if it's exist

Comment: @Dejavu it works fine with `/` in the middle of the string https://3v4l.org/rtOfE

Answer (score 1):

You can get it done with a simple regex where every character except alphanumeric or underscore or hyphen will be replaced with empty string and more than two forward slashes at the end of string will be replaced with single `/` . Just replace this regex,

```
[^\w-/]+|(/)/+$
```

With `\1`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jI1W1q/3)**

PHP Demo,

```
$s = "controller_123/method///";
echo preg_replace('@[^\w-/]|(/)/+$@', '\1', $s);
```

Prints,

```
controller_123/method/
```

Comment: This answer is the right solution. It just could have a `+` quantifier on `[^\w-/]`.

Comment: @revo: Yes you're right. Adding a `+` will make it better. Thanks for the suggestion. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following regex(considering that your input will be as shown samples only):

```
.*\w\/
```

[Regex DEMO:](https://regex101.com/r/mxoBFu/1/)

In `php` try to do following.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Online PHP Script Execution</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
   echo "<h1>Hello, PHP!</h1>\n";
   $string = 'controller_123/method///';
   preg_match('/.*\w\//', $string, $matches);
   print_r($matches);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Is giving me following output in online terminal when I test it.

```
$php main.php
<html>
<head>
<title>Online PHP Script Execution</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello, PHP!</h1>
Array
(
    [0] => controller_123/method/
)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That actually removes everything before last slash. I need to keep this part actually

Comment: @Dejavu, yes because you are putting into regex_replace function you need to put this regex into a function which prints only matched regex.

Comment: @Dejavu, could you please try my edited answer now with php flavor?

Comment: It doesn't work correctly if there is no forward slash at the end of string. controller_123/method returns as controller_123/

Comment: @Dejavu, please check my update here I have mentioned what output I am getting while executing the php code.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expression

```
$string=preg_replace("//$/", '', $string );
```

Using strripos() and strreplace

```
$string=str_replace(strripos("/",$string),"",$string)
```

Using rtrim()

```
$string=rtrim("/",$string);
```

Comment: Notice that rtrim removes all slashes from the end. I just want to keep 1 occurrence

Answer (score 0):

This task can be accomplished with no lookarounds, no capture groups, a single pattern, and a single empty replacement string.

```
[^-\w/]+   #match one or more non-dash, non-word, non-slash characters
|          #or
/\K/+$     #match a slash, then forget it, them match one or more slash until the end of the string
```

I'll demonstrate on an array of strings, but `preg_replace()` will just as happily replace a string as the third parameter.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VpiUo))

```
$strings = [
    'controller_123/method///',
    'controller_123/method/',
    '% con $trol@$@ler_!123/me*thod////',
];

var_export(
    preg_replace(
        '~[^-\w/]+|/\K/+$~',
        '',
        $strings
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'controller_123/method/',
  1 => 'controller_123/method/',
  2 => 'controller_123/method/',
)
```